# The view 'Index' or its master could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, view, asp.net-mvc-routing

Today I've started restructuring my mvc project using areas. So I have some problems with it.
I make areas, move views and master pages, make routing, but when I'm trying to view any area page I get "The view 'Login' or its master could not be found."

Any suggestions? I've googled for some time, but didn't found any solution.

My global.asax routing:

```
routes.MapRoute("Areaname", "Areaname",
                            "Areaname/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                            new { controller = "controllerName", action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                            new string[] { "path.to.area.controllers.Controllers" });
```

Area registration routing:

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context)
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Areaname_default",
                "Areaname/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Home", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                new string[] { "path.to.area.controllers.Controllers" }
            );
        }
```

It seems to be correct, but views are still unavailable.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Something tells me you have authentication with a login redirect triggering (due to setting in web.config). Does that path conform to the new design as well?

Comment: I don't have any authentication in my app

Answer (score 0):

When using Areas, make sure you rewrite your action links like this:

```
 Html.ActionLink("Invoicing link", "Index", "CustomerInvoices", new { area = "Invoicing" }, null)
```

In this example, you are linking to the "Index" action, inside "CustomerInvoices" controller, inside "Invoicing" Area.

Make sure you do the proper modifications to link to the Login action inside your Area!